# Website wont run certain queries after changing servers

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a website running on a test server with the path in appsetting in my web.config file

```
<appSettings>
<add key="CompanyName" value="Own Company"/>
<add key="TMConString" value="Data Source=zautn8\test228; Initial
Catalog=System; User ID=s_man; pwd=s_2Mn"/>         
<add key="TM_Admin" value="GA_PRODADMIN"/>
<add key="TM_Management" value="GA_PRODREP"/>
</appSettings>
```

Now when i change this(above code) to point to the live server all the scripts run except for one

```
dtData = DBA.Execute("SELECT Set_ID, Set_Name + ' - ' +  Set_Desc As Set_N  FROM  
[Set]  ORDER by Set_Name ASC").Tables(0)
ddlSet.DataTextField = "Set_N"
ddlSet.DataValueField = "Set_ID"
ddlSet.DataSource = dtData
ddlSet.DataBind()
If cmd = "edit" Then
Dim i_Set As Integer = Inc.makeNumeric(s_Set)
ddlSet.SelectedValue = i_Set
End If
ddlSet.Attributes("onchange") = "javascript:getData();"
dtData.Clear()
dtData.Dispose()
```

This is the vb code that runs in the code behind pages not in the aspx. Any ideas as to what could cause this? Havent changed anything except the connection to the server to point to live instead of test

Comment: Posting your error might be useful.

Comment: The thing is it doesn't give an error, it literally skips that one query but runs all the others

Comment: If by which you mean it doesn't give any results, then is there any data in your live DB?  If not, could you expand on 'skips'?

Comment: When i run a trace through the code it executes all the queries except one. On the live server some of the tables are empty but the one that this particular sql statement is running to is not empty

Comment: @Paddy i sorted it out, the problem was with my dtData(datatable). I was reading from two tables and one table was empty so it used the indexes from that table to load my dropdown list. I just seperated the code and loaded dtData on two different occasions. But your comment about the DB being empty led me to it, THANKS :)